# How to raise each element of each row of matrix M to the power of each element of vector x in C++ using Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using the Eigen library to perform the following operation. Given a matrix `M` and a vector `x`, I would like to raise each row of `M` to the power of `x` element-wise. That is, if `M = [[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 40], [40, 50]]` and `x = [2, 3]`, I would like to get a result of `[[100, 8000], [400, 27000], [900, 64000], [1600, 125000]]`. Is there a way of achieving this using Eigen's SIMD features and without any explicit for loop?

I tried the following code

```
VectorXd func() { 
    // [[10, 20], 
    //  [20, 30], 
    //  [30, 40], 
    //  [40, 50]]
    Eigen::MatrixXd M(4, 2);
    M(0, 0) = 10; M(0, 1) = 20;
    M(1, 0) = 20; M(1, 1) = 30;
    M(2, 0) = 30; M(2, 1) = 40;
    M(3, 0) = 40; M(3, 1) = 50; 

    std::vector<double> x_numbers  = {2, 3}; 
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> x(x_numbers.data(), x_numbers.size());

    auto retval = M.array().pow(x.array()); 
    // I expect a 4x2 matrix returned but I am getting a vector of 
    // size two instead. Changing the return type to MatrixXd 
    // does not help either. 
    return retval;
}
```

However, the return value of this function for the above values of `M` and `x` is `[100, 8000]`. I also tried `M.array().rowwise().pow(x.array())` but I get "error: no member named 'pow' ...".  What am I missing? I am using Eigen-3.4.0.

Comment: I'm getting the return value `[0.999996, 0.999995]` but perhaps I didn't fill in the blanks properly. Can you turn this into a [mre]?

Comment: The `M` in your code isn't the same as the one in the text above. The `M` in your code is `[[10, 30], [20, 40], [20, 40], [30, 50]]` - Which one is correct?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is odd but I updated the code and created the matrix more explicitly (the code is the reference). Anyway, the issue I am having is the structure of the returned value as I expect a 4x2 matrix returned but I am getting a vector of size two instead.

Comment: Ok, I see that now the `M`s and the return values match. You added a Map that wasn't included in the original version of the function though. You could also create `M` simpler: `MatrixXd M{{10, 20}, {20, 30}, {30, 40}, {40, 50}};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working with Eigen's array operations, either both operands need to be the same shape, or one of them is a scalar. Because you want an operation between matrix and a vector, you need to broadcast the vector to match the matrix first. This can be done with the `replicate` function.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd func1(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M, const Eigen::VectorXd& x) {
    return M.array().pow(x.transpose().array().replicate(M.rows(),1));
}
```

[See Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7E5bnozh3)

If you want to avoid the extra copies of `x` then you can only work on a column by column basis with `M` and you will need to write a for loop, but Eigen's array operation can still be used:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd func2(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M, const Eigen::VectorXd& x) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd retval(M.rows(), M.cols());
    for (Eigen::Index col = 0; col < M.cols(); ++col) {
        retval.col(col) = M.col(col).array().pow(x(col));
    }
    return retval;
}
```

(In the demo is an extra version using `NullaryExpr` which is not using a for loop but does not exhibit Eigen's array operations)

Comment: Re "If you want to avoid the extra copies of `x`": `.replicate()` itself will not produce any copies. With optimizations (and probably `-DNDEBUG`) `func1` and `func2` should be practically equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

When you call `M.array().pow(x.array())`, it’s raising each element of `M` to the corresponding element of `x` for each corresponding element of `M` and `x`. That’s why you’re only getting the first two elements of the result you expect. It is not doing the multiplication for each row of `M` with the vector `x`.

Here’s how you can modify your function:

```
MatrixXd func(const Ref<const Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor>>& M, VectorXd x) { 
    auto retval = M.array().pow(x.transpose().array().replicate(M.rows(),1));
    return retval;
}
```

`x.transpose().array().replicate(M.rows(),1)` creates a matrix where each row is the vector `x`, and then `M.array().pow(...)` raises each row of `M` to the corresponding row of that matrix.

**Edit:** Sorry, there was an error in the code. It has been fixed and the answer is updated now.

Output:

```
Result:
   100   8000
   400  27000
   900  64000
  1600 125000
```

Comment: What version of Eigen do you use? This doesn't compile for me in Eigen 3.4